# How can an inconsistent JSON response be parsed into either one of two subclasses?

Tags: java, android, json, rest, gson

I am using Retrofit2 with Gson to retrieve and parse JSON strings from a restful web service into an Android client.

I have something similar to the following mock classes:

```
public class User {
    String name;
    String email;
    String gender;
    String phone;
    String type;

    //getters and setters.
}
```

And 2 sub-classes (maybe more in the future):

ShopOwner:

```
public class ShopOwner extends User {
    String shopName;
    String shopDescription;
    Country shopCountry;

    //getters and setters.
}
```

And Buyer:

```
public class Buyer extends User {
    float availableCredit;
    long lastPurchase;

    /getters and setters.
}
```

- *Serializing Annotations omitted for brevity.*

When I fire the login request, and on successful login, I receive either one of the following JSON responses:

This:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "john@doe.com",
    "gender": "male",
    "phone": "1234567890",
    "type": "shop owner",
    "shop_owner": {
        "shop_name": "Flower Market",
        "shop_description": "Fresh Flowers Everyday",
        "shop_country": {
            "name": "United Stated of America",
            "short_name": "US"
        }
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "john@doe.com",
    "gender": "male",
    "phone": "1234567890",
    "type": "buyer",
    "buyer": {
        "available_credit": 200,
        "last_purchase": 1527915600
    }
}
```

And so my questions are:

1) Is the structure of the response I am receiving considered a "best practice"? Or should the guys at the backend restructure the response to combine the keys from the super class and the sub-class into one object? This way I can simply check the type attribute, and parse the object to either of the 2 sub-classes accordingly.

2) If the response I am receiving is actually structured according to best practices, how can I efficiently parse it? A TypeAdapter seems a ridiculous answer, since, seriously, I have to store all the values in variables waiting for the type key from the stream, this does not sound nice at all! Another approach would be to make the sub-classes composites inside the User class, and I really do not like this solution as well, since one or the other will always be null, and I believe inheritance was created to be used in these situations.

Your help is dearly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

To rephrase, I think having to deal with a such structured JSON string using a TypeAdapter is 'ridiculous', since I believe the JSON should be structured in another fashion that fits the inheritance concept. Here is a sample of what a TypeAdapter's read method might look like for the simple mock classes provided in my example:

```
public User read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        reader.nextNull();
        return null;
    }
    boolean isShopOwner = true;
    User user = new User();
    HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
    Country country = new Country();
    reader.beginObject();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String key = reader.nextName();
        switch (key) {
            case "shop_owner":
            case "buyer":
                if (key.equals("buyer"))
                    isShopOwner = false;
                reader.beginObject();
                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                    String key2 = reader.nextName();
                    if (key2.equals("country")) {
                        reader.beginObject();
                        while (reader.hasNext()) {
                            switch (reader.nextName()) {
                                case "name":
                                    country.setName(reader.nextString());
                                    break;
                                case "short_name":
                                    country.setShortName(reader.nextString());
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        reader.endObject();
                    }
                    else
                        values.put(key2, reader.nextString());
                }
                reader.endObject();
                break;
            default:
                values.put(key, reader.nextString());
        }
    }
    user.setName(values.get("name"));
    user.setEmail(values.get("email"));
    user.setGender(values.get("gender"));
    user.setPhone(values.get("phone"));
    user.setType(values.get("type"));
    if (isShopOwner) {
        ShopOwner shopOwner = user;
        shopOwner.setShopName(values.get("shop_name"));
        shopOwner.setShopDescription(values.get("shop_description"));
        shopOwner.setCountry(country);
        return shopOwner;
    }
    else {
        Buyer buyer = user;
        buyer.setAvailableCredit(values.get("available_credit"));
        buyer.setLastPurchase(values.get("last_purchase"));
        return buyer;
    }
}
```

My actual classes are far more complex, and they nest many objects within, in addition to the fact that I have to check the instance I get back from the read method, since I do not really know if it is going to return a ShopOwner or a Buyer object. I am sure there has to be a cleaner approach!

Comment: I would rather change the keys `shop_owner` and `buyer` to `user` since the user type is defined in `type`. Other than that I find no problem in it.

Comment: You're asking for efficiency, but type adapters are ridiculous to you? May I ask you: why?

Comment: Could you not just use a conditional statement to check if the Json object is of a particular type?

Comment: Performance aside, that data structure is definitely odd. I would suggest a structure like this instead: "buyer": {"name": "x", "e-mail": "y"}

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv I have edited the question to explain why a TypeAdapter is not the best answer to my question.

Comment: @zed Assume the keys have been changed to user, how would you proceed to parse it into the mock classes afterwards?

Comment: @JordanH Yes, I can, but then again I will have to write my own adapter to parse the JSON, is this the best possible structure for a JSON file that returns an inherited object?